# Help with action MAIL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
require 'config/environment'

inquiry               = Inquiry.find(:all, :conditions => ["is_answered = 0"])

inquiry.each do |i|   
    question          = i.question 
    user              = User.find(:first, :conditions => ["id = ?", question.user_id])

    Notifier.deliver_deadline_notification(inquiry, user, question)
end
```

I have table `inquiry` (relationship table) with `is_answered` field (for example).

What I need? I need to send email people who are `NOT answered` on my question (`is_answered = 0`). So Now works this way: i received `2` emails (because  i have in database 1 question and 2 users who are not answered) :

```
id | question_id | is_answered
14 |     11      |     0
24 |     11      |     0
```

So, i need to receive `ONLY ONE EMAIL` not two!!! In email i want to write some statistics about question. But i need only ONE EMAIL! how can i possible do it ?

thank you!

------------------UPD-----------------

```
model/notifier.rb
  def deadline_notification(inquiry, user, question, respondent)
     recipients   user.email
     from         "hey@hey.com"
     subject      "Finished"
     content_type "text/html"
     body(:question => question.text, :respondent => respondent.email)
  end

model/inquiry

class Inquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :question
  belongs_to  :respondent
  has_one     :answer, :dependent => :destroy

model/question

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inquiries, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :answers, :through => :inquiries, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user
end

model/respondent

class Respondent < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many    :inquiries, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many    :questions, :through => :inquiries
  belongs_to  :user
end

model/user

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :respondents
```

TODO: find all inquries where is_answered = 0 (For example i have 100 respondents, and 70 people are answered) and send ME email (user, who added question ok, (it is working)) that 70 respondents answered (AND WHO EXACTLY) and who not answered. JUST SEND ONE EMAIL!

PS - Now i received 30 emails (who are not answered), but i think it is wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to do here is to find all users who have not answered questions on an inquiry -so something like

```
`User.all(:includes=>[:questions, :inquiries], :conditions=>["is_answered=?",0])
```

Then you can pass the collections (inquiries,questions) to the view and iterate through to list your statistics

Hope I made this clear - if not perhaps I can do better if you post the associations on the models and the view you are using for the mailer ...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think see what you are doing now!  How about

```
#get all unanswered inquiries
inquiries = Inquiry.find(:all, :conditions => ["is_answered = 0"])

#get all users who have unanswered inquiries and build a hash {:user=>[inquiries]}
user_hash= inquiries.inject({})(|uh,i| uh.key?(i.question.user) ? uh[i.question.user] << i : uh[i.question.user]=>[i]
uh)


#iterate thro the users and send a mail to each ...
user_hash.each do |user, inquiries|   
#obviously your existing view won't work here - you need to iterate thro inquiries
Notifier.deliver_deadline_notification(user, inquiries)
end
```